# Usage de "forensique"

Tags: usage, synonymes, droit-et-justice

Le mot forensique est un calque anglais (selon les dictionnaires) et synonyme du mot criminalistique. Peut-on l'utiliser couramment ? Google traduit le texte :

> Forensic experts will try to estimate this time from the body’s current temperature and calculate how long it would have had to lose heat to reach that temperature.

par

> Les experts en médecine légale tenteront d'estimer ce temps à partir de la température actuelle du corps et de calculer combien de temps il aurait fallu perdre de la chaleur pour atteindre cette température.

"Médecine légale" est-il plus reconnu ?

Comment: Je ne trouve ce terme dans aucun dictionnaire que je peux consulter. TLFi, Académie, Larousse.

Comment: @Toto : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/forensique

Comment: Non seulement "*forensique*" sera considéré comme un anglicisme (à juste titre), mais surtout je pense qu'une bonne partie des français ne comprendront pas le terme. Ce n'est pas le mot anglais le plus commun en français. D'ailleurs, "*Médecine légale*" n'est pas la seule traduction possible. Celles données par [wordreference](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/forensic) me semblent pertinentes et idiomatiques.

Comment: Le terme est effectivement utilisé (du moins il l'était dans les années 2000) dans la Gendarmerie Nationale. Pas dans les rapports officiels certes, mais dans le langage courant pour désigner la médecine légale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personnellement, j'en ai vaguement entendu parler dans un cadre de sécurité informatique sans avoir bien compris ce que cela regroupait.

Je pense qu'il est hasardeux de l'utiliser, dans le sens où peu de personnes seront susceptibles de connaitre sa signification; alors que « Experts en médecine légale » sera compris par tout le monde.

Comment: Dans la sécurité informatique, ne s'agit-il pas d'analyser des preuves permettant de remonter à l'origine d'un *crash* (plantage) ou d'un *hack* (piratage) ? Cela correspondrait soit à une recherche théorique des causes d'un problème (ce qui relève de l'étiologie, terme soit médical, soit plus généralement épistémologique), soit simplement à une *enquête* (recherche d'indices ou de preuves destinés à établir la cause, l'origine ou la responsabilité d'un incident).